# Is it possible to update my cherry mobile flare lite 2 from kitkat to Lollipop?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I have cherry mobile flare lite 2 and I want to experience lollipop but I don't know, I can't find update for my phone

Answer (score 0):

When you cannot find an update in your phone's updater or on its official website, the android version you are looking for is probably not supported by your phone. If you want to install Lollipop on your phone anyway, you might want to try a [Custom-Rom](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device).

But be aware: some of the options presented to you can **void your warranty or damage your phone**. I also cannot guarantee you will find something that works for you at all. More information on this can be found in the post I linked you.